# Search and Replace Byte Order Mark In Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, encoding, byte-order-mark

i have 10 table and more than 10000 record that contain `ï»¿`
how can search `ï»¿` and replace this in DB?
since the  `ï»¿` equal `0xEF,0xBB,0xBF` how can search this?

i use this code

```
 WITH foo(myvarbincolumn) AS
(
SELECT text from BPM_Letters
)
SELECT *
FROM   foo
WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), myvarbincolumn) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS
                    LIKE '%' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), CHAR(0xEF)+CHAR(0xBB)+CHAR(0xBF)) + '%'
```

I found this code in stackoverflow but it s incomplete.

[script of `BPM_Letters`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-NJ1J4kViZhcTRfWmxrMVBBNXM/view?usp=sharing)
this code not find any record!
please help me

Comment: What is your table name that you're wanting to search?  All the code provided is doing is searching a CTE of one record for the same value (which is working correctly).

Comment: table name is 'BPM_letters' and column is 'text'

Comment: So you're wanting to replace `ï»¿` with `0xEFBBBF`?

Comment: What is the type of column 'text'?

Comment: Are you replacing the entire column, or just `ï»¿` within the text?

Comment: type `text` is `nvarchar(MAX)` and i want replace only `ï»¿` in text  with '' or null

Comment: select text from BPM_letters where text like N'%ï»¿%' should give you all rows containing these special characters, right?

Comment: @ Giorgos Betsos:no this does not work.because `ï»¿` is not string !

Comment: select text from BPM_letters where text like CHAR(0xEF)+CHAR(0xBB)+CHAR(0xBF) does not work\

Comment: @MSS Sorry, but I fail to underastand you correctly. If ï»¿ is not a string or a character, then how is it contained inside an nvarchar column?

Comment: @Giorgos please read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: What is the actual problem with this code? Does it find the records you're looking for?

Comment: this code not find any recode

Comment: Can you show some sample data then?  Or perhaps, remove the `COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS`?

Comment: Why are you using `VARCHAR` anywhere? Everything should be `NVARCHAR`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a query to find that weird character via the query below:

```
SELECT cast(LEFT(text,1) AS VARBINARY(MAX)) from BPM_Letters
```

and the result was 0xFFFE. So I wrote this query and it worked perfectly:

```
UPDATE BPM_Letters Set text=REPLACE(text,0xFFFE,'');
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this CTE:

```
StripBOM AS
(
   SELECT CASE
             WHEN LEFT(text,3) = 0xEFBBBF
                THEN CONVERT(varbinary(max),SUBSTRING(text, 4, LEN(text)))
             ELSE text             
           END AS text
   FROM BPM_Letters
)
```

It should provide you with a new table where all BOM characters have been stripped off.

P.S. This code assumes '`text`' field is of type `varbinary`.

Comment: and how can replace `ï»¿` with ''?

Comment: @Seyed BOM byte sequence is contained always at the beginning. SUBSTRING(text, 4, LEN(text)) simply strips this byte sequence off.

Comment: in comments @MISS say:type text is nvarchar(MAX).how can work with nvarchar?

Comment: Thank @GiorgosBetsos Your Idea Of Getting First Character Help Too Much.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler answer that builds on the other ones:

```
UPDATE BPM_Letters SET text=substr(text, 4) WHERE left(text, 3) = 0xEFBBBF;
```

I've tested this, and it works.

Comment: It Was Two Byte I Dont Know How But I Doesnt Worked For Me!